# how to use tooltip in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

how to use tooltip in objective C?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to be less vague.

Comment: @Rulmeq:  "How to use tooltip?"

Answer (score 0):

Not all objects support ToolTips, those that do typically have the common tooltip / setToolTip methods to deal with them programatically.  Typically you set them / localize them through IB, at least that's how the projects I have worked on in the past have done it.